# UITableViewCell auto height based on amount of UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, xcode8

I have a bit of a tricky set up in my storyboard, I have a UIViewController that holds a UITableViewController. Within the UITableViewController I have several prototypecells I have linked to subclassed uitableviewcell objects in code.

Using constraints and storyboard I would like to change the height of my prototype cell depending on the size the UILabel ends up being which is dependant on the text going into it.

Currently I have a

```
UIViewController
-- UITableViewController
-- -- UITableViewCell ((melchat) prototype cell)
-- -- -- ContentView
-- -- -- -- UIView ((background) view with drop shadow card type effect)
-- -- -- -- -- UIImageView (Avatar)
-- -- -- -- -- IUlabel (dynamic (depending on code/input) multi line UILabel)
```

Some how I would like the UILabel to resize the UIView (background) then in turn effect the height of that UITableViewCell.

I am using XCode 8.2.1

I have taken a screen shot of the layout in storyboard and constraints applied.

[image]

### Update

I have updated my constraints to pretty much all go back to ContentView and have updated uilabel line count to 0 and then also implemented the UITableViewAutomaticDimension code but its still not working. Please see code and screen shots below.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove Avatar image view bottom constrain and set label bottom constrain
also set rowheight and estimated row height

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To go a little further on Dao's answer..

He is correct, you need to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Also, you need to ensure that you setup your constraints in a way that all of the content in the cell is constrained to the cells contentView. So your label will likely need constraints such as

- Leading constraint to ImageView
- Top constraint to contentView
- Bottom constraint to contentView
- Trailing constraint to contentView

Make sure that you set the UILabel to multiline (or lines = 0) and it should work.

If you are using the heightForRowAt delegate functions ensure you return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: I have updated my question I might not have understood your answer.. as it didnt quite work. thnks for your response.

Comment: your constraint for the label to uiimagview should be label.leading = imageview.trailing + 10 (or whatever distance you want). currently it looks in the screenshot like there is still a height set. or is that the old screenshot?

Comment: I am still working on it. cannot get it to work for some reason.

Comment: Okay I kind of have it working.. my only issue now is that my image height is massive. so im going to fix that lol

Comment: yeah it just looks like the constraints need adjusting, if you can put your project on github I can take a look if your still struggling

Answer (score 13):

Use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

Answer (score 9):

step1:Give below constraint to UIView that is inside to the contentView.

- Leading constraint to contentView
- Top constraint to contentView
- Bottom constraint to contentView
- Trailing constraint to contentView

step2: Give below constraint to UIlabel

- Leading constraint to UIImageView
- Top constraint to UIView
- Bottom constraint to UIView
- Trailing constraint to UIView

step3: Then select your Trailing constraint of IUlabel and select edit option and then select constant and select greaterThanEqual option.

step4: set label's `numberofline = 0`

step5:  Add this code into `viewDidLoad()`

```
yourtableview.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
yourtableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4.2 and 5**. As mention above you can set UITableView object property or

```
tblView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension 
tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
```

you can also define the same by implementing UITableViewDelegate methods

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
      }
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

After populating the UILabel and applying constrains, get the height of the label and set it as the height of the UIView.

After that call `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and pass the height of the UILabel/UIView so that it gets the actual height for that row