# Dynamic height for UITableViewCell not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, swift4

I'm having some height problems with my dynamic `UITableViewCell` (sew picture below). Some cells have the correct height and some not, and when I drag the tableView some of the cells become correct and some don't.

I'm using this code to get the cell's height to be dynamic and reloading it in `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad`.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
```

As mentioned the cells are sometimes correct and sometimes not. Is there another way to do it or am I doing something wrong? I have tried many different solutions, all mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494702/dynamic-height-issue-for-uitableview-cells-swift) as well as other suggestions both here at StackOverflow and other sites.

[image]

[image]

I appreciate all help!

Edit!

TableView

```
extension ChatVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return groupMessages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupFeedCell", for: indexPath) as? GroupFeedCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        let message = groupMessages[indexPath.row]

            DataService.instance.getUsername(forUID: message.senderId, handler: { (name) in
                cell.configureCell(name: name, content: message.content)
            })

        cell.layoutSubviews()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 66
    }
}
```

Cell

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentLbl: UILabel!

func configureCell(name: String, content: String) {
    self.nameLbl.text = name //email
    self.contentLbl.text = content
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you change the number of label lines to 0?

Comment: Yes I have done that

Comment: I hope you are not providing random data when you're cell is dequeuing

Comment: No, I'm taking down all the data from firebase.

Comment: have you implemented estimated height and height for row delegate?

Comment: **func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {**

and 

**func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {**

Comment: Yes it is set to 66 both at the tableView and tableViewCell in interfacebuilder

Comment: implement this delegate   

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight change to tableView.estimatedRowHeight = [Your NIB or Prototype cell height]

Comment: See my answer here, it should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717173/uitableviewcell-auto-height-based-on-amount-of-uilabel-text/42717313#42717313. you need to make sure constraints cover all sides to contentView, especially nameLbl

Comment: @AlizainPrasla I tries that also.

Comment: @Scriptable I look through your answer and I have done all the steps there.

Comment: All of the advice given so far should solve the issue. the issue is either within your code or constraints. please post your code for the cell and tableview

Comment: @Scriptable see above, also the picture of the constraints

Comment: estimatedHeightForRowAt should return an value for an estimated height, it allows the tableview to reserve some space. it should not return automatic

Comment: Oh yes ofc. Changed that now. Have you seen the constraints?

Comment: yeah, checking them over now. I think i know what your issue is, but working out how to best explain

Comment: provide controller code or tableview delegate and datasource code

Comment: you are getting the response in cellForRow. fetch your required data first then reload.

Answer (score 3):

For dynamic *tableViewCell*

1- Setup this 2 lines with an inital value for the row height to help autolayout drawing it (take it from current cell height in the nib file)

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = number;
```

2- don't implement this function **heightForRowAtIndexPath** . or implement it and return this

```
return UITableViewDynamicHeight;
```

3- make sure all constraints in the cell nib file or in storyboard are hooked correctly from top to bottom.

4- in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** before the line *retrun cell* insert that

```
[cell layoutSubviews];
[cell layoutIfneeded];
```

5- Test in simulator some versions like ios 8 it's a bug also in the viewController call

```
[tableView LayouSubviews];
```

in viewdidLayoutSubViews function to re relayout again correctly

6- Make **lines** property of any **UILabel** that you want to wrap = 0 and hook it's **leading** and **trailing** constarints to superView

Answer (score 1):

Your are facing this issue because the content of your label comes from an async function.

The cell uses its content to work out its height dynamically. When your async request returns it has already done its work and will not recalculate and resize.

You need to make these requests, cache/store the results and reload the cells as needed. Usually in chat there would only be a couple of users to load usernames for anyway. You could also try pre-loading this data before the chat is displayed.

You can quickly confirm this by creating an array of random usernames and messages (sample data) and adding that to the cell straight away.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is asynchronous function. So Should you try

Step 1: Create names array

> ```
> var names: [String?] = Array<String>.init(repeating: nil, count: groupMessages.count)
> ```

Step 2: Replace

```
 DataService.instance.getUsername(forUID: message.senderId, handler: { (name) in
                cell.configureCell(name: name, content: message.content)
            })
```

By

```
 if names[indexPath.row] == nil {
            DataService.instance.getUsername(forUID: message.senderId, handler: { (name) in
                names[indexPath.row] = name

                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            })
        } else {
            cell.configureCell(name: name, content: message.content)

        }
```