# how to increase cell height dynamically in swift 4

Tags: swift

I am new in swift and I am trying to create a school project. The problem I face is I have multiple cells and I don't know how to increase the cell height. I have searched, but I am not able to understand how to do it.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The better approach is to make use of auto layout and `UITableView`'s "estimated" support - See [Self-sizing Table View Cells](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1067-self-sizing-table-view-cells) for starters

Comment: Possible duplicate [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) and [UITableViewCell auto height based on amount of UILabel text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717173/uitableviewcell-auto-height-based-on-amount-of-uilabel-text/42717313)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Implement the following table view method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

//return the size of your cell

    }
```

Like if your cell height is 190 then simply return 190 here.