# Dynamically change cell height according to label text

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, dynamic-sizing

I tried to add Q&A part for my app and that tableview cell have to expand according to text height, cell height have to change with this text. In this point I did some thing to solve problem which are numberOfline = 0 and UITableView.automaticDimension code can't solve my problem. Here my code from project :

Problem is cell height didn't change this code just write label under the questions and for longer answers under the next question. Means cell height didn't change.

```
let soruLabel: UILabel = {
    let sorulabel = UILabel()
    sorulabel.textColor = .darkGray
    sorulabel.numberOfLines = 0
    sorulabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    return sorulabel
}()

let cevapLabel: UILabel = {
    let cevaplabel = UILabel()
    cevaplabel.textColor = .black
    cevaplabel.numberOfLines = 0
    cevaplabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
    return cevaplabel
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setup()
}

func set(content: expandingTableCellForsss) {
    self.soruLabel.text = content.soru
    self.cevapLabel.text = content.expanded ? content.cevap : ""
}

func setup() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 245, green: 245, blue: 245, alpha: 1)


    addSubview(soruLabel)
    addSubview(cevapLabel)


    soruLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    soruLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    soruLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    soruLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = false
    soruLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true

    cevapLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cevapLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: soruLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    cevapLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    cevapLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: soruLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = false
    cevapLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true




}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: To use UITableView.automaticDimension you also need to set estimatedHeightForRowAt

Comment: check the bottom constraint of cevapLabel, it is not connected to the container view's bottom. just in case also check the content hugging priority.

Comment: Shouldn't the cevapLabel bottom anchor be equal to bottomAnchor and active? Specifically: cevapLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true?

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD Thank you so much solve my problem.

Comment: @eksglox no problem, I added it as an answer so other users can find it easily. Please mark as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom anchor needs to be set:

```
cevapLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check :
[UITableViewCell auto height based on amount of UILabel text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717173/uitableviewcell-auto-height-based-on-amount-of-uilabel-text/42717313) ,

[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

To use dynamic cell height:
1) give a minimum row height for cell in viewDidLoad

tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300

2) set rowHeight property of tableview as automatic in viewDidLoad

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

3) in storyboard select numberOfLines = 0

4) if you have provided custom height to cell in storyBoard, make sure its equal to estimated row height.