# Tableview cell height as per content in it

Tags: ios, swift

Using swift5 i tried below code but unable to make it a adjustable height of cell. Any one can help me in that?

```swift
    tableView.rowHeight = tableView.frame.height/8
```

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

**Now**
[image]

**what I want**

[image]

**View Architecture**

[image]

**Cell Architecture**
[image]

Comment: You are looking for [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview) method, that's where you should return `tableHeight / 8`

Comment: If you are looking for dynamic height of the tableview, you can assign
`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 // you cell's height`
 `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` and also you can take height constraint of tableview and write `        self.tblHConstraint.constant = self.tblOfferView.contentSize.height` in `willDisplay cell` method

Answer (score 1):

## Auto height

You need to confirm to `UITableViewDelegate` and then call these two methods.

```
func tableView(UITableView, heightForRowAt: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

#### Or

```
tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

But in both cases, it is required the views in cell have both bottom and top constraints. Read the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717173/uitableviewcell-auto-height-based-on-amount-of-uilabel-text/42717313) for more info.

#### More info.

[UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

[Configuring Cell Height and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview)

Comment: Thank you for ur answer.I've tried the answer but the cell height only changed by _return 100_...and I added the cell architect I think added the constraint already.where did I miss???is's too tricky...@mahan

Comment: @tzxdtc10 I do not know if it is tricky for you. Do you need to have auto height or fixed height (table.frame.height/8) ? `print(table.frame.height)` in one of the above methods should you have fixed height. I think it is either `0` or `nill`.

Comment: @tzxdtc10 I updated the asnwere. There was a problem. Return  `return UITableView.automaticDimension` in `heightForRowAt` method and `100` in `estimatedHeightForRowAt`

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but it did not work for me .Finally, I change the tableView to UIView.